# How to dynamically bind a WPF Controls property with ViewModels different property?

Tags: c#, wpf

For Example:
We need to dynamically bind a RadioButton Value property with two different properties of ViewModel.

**View Model**

```
public class MyViewModel
{

//Property-1 to bind with RadioButton
        public bool Accepted
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

//Property-2 to bind with RadioButton
        public bool Enable
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

//Property to Identify which property should bind with radio button.
        public bool Mode
        {
            get;
            set;           
        }
}
```

**Xaml**

```
<RadioButton Value="{Binding Accepted, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

> Is it possible to dynamically bind Accepted or Enable property
>   according to the Mode property?

- One solution came up is using IMultiValueConverter and MultiBinding. Is it a proper method?

Comment: Do you have control over the viewmodel? why not bind to a new property who's value reflects the value of Accepted or Enable based on the value of Mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change the binding from the view model. You could however create a new property which you bind to that then delegates its value to the correct other value, e.g.:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public bool Prop1 { get; set; }
    public bool Prop2 { get; set; }
    public bool Use2 { get; set; }

    public bool Prop
    {
        get { return Use2 ? Prop2 : Prop1; }
        set
        {
            if (Use2)
                Prop2 = value;
            else
                Prop1 = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Of course this example is missing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation details.

Comment: We need to NotifyPropertyChanged for new property while each property's changes. RIght ?

Comment: Yeah, the event needs to be there for every property which changes you want to affect the view. So in this case, you could only implement it for `Prop` but when you change any of the other tree properties, you need to remember to also raise the event for `Prop` since that’s what will indirectly change and then update the view.